# ASP.NET Mvc convert <%@ Import Namespace="Thirpartynamespace" %> to Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to convert the mvc 3 aspx view engine to razor view engine below:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="ThirdpartyComp.Web.UI" %> 
<% = Html.SomeFunction("Test")%>
```

to:

```
@using ThirdpartyComp.Web.UI
@Html.SomeFunction("Test")
```

When I do @html.SomeFunction(... I get this exeption:

*`Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`*

Could anyone please confirm if above is possible, and anything that I'm missing?

Thank you heaps.

Comment: Typo or did you really enter *We.UI* instead of *Web.UI*?

Comment: @tvanfosson, it's typo thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets are precisely equivalent. The problem lies somewhere else. Ensure that you have referenced the assembly containing this helper to the new project (Add Reference... in the project) and that this assembly is compatible with ASP.NET MVC 3 i.e. it depends on the System.Web.Mvc V3 instead of V2. If this is not the case you might need to recompile it against ASP.NET MVC 3 (if you have the source code) or ask the author for a version which is compatible with it.

Comment: @Darin, thanks for your precise answer. I think you are spot on. I already have added the Reference but as you said the third party component may not support MVC3. However, it works if used aspx engine instead for MVC 3.0.Any thoughts?

Comment: @flybyte, oh, then normally it should be compatible. Could you post the exact exception your are getting along the stack trace?

Comment: @flybyte, could you please post the full exception stacktrace you are getting when you run your application?

Comment: @Darin, I get "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" message when I type @Html.SomeFunction(...". I'm assuming that this means view is not aware of ThirdpartyComp.Web.UI?

Comment: @flybyte, do you get the same error if you run the application?